# How to take address of argument with reflection

Tags: go, reflection

Basic situation:

you can do this in golang:

```
func addrOf(foo interface{}) interface{} {
    return &foo
}
```

but you cannot do this:

```
func addrOf(foo interface{}) interface{} {
    fooValue := reflect.ValueOf(foo)
    return fooValue.Addr().Interface()
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? why is `foo` addressable to the language but not to reflect?

Comment: `foo` the `interface{}` is addressable, but the value within the interface is not. I don't think the first example does what you think it does.

Comment: The value of the argument `foo` is passed to `reflect.Value`. It's impossible for reflect to discover the address of the argument from the value stored in the argument.